# Printing pointer's address in C

Tags: c, printf

I'm reproducing printf from scrap and I need to store pointers address into a string then print it, so first I cast void* into an unsigned int then itoa it to hexadecimal but the last three char are wrong.

```
int     main(void)
{
    char    str[] = "printf from scrap!";

    my_printf("MY_PRINTF:'%p'", (void*)str);
    printf("\n   PRINTF:'%p'\n\n", (void*)str);

    return (0);
}

int     conv_p(va_list args)
{
    void    *ptr;
    unsigned int        ptrint;

    ptr = va_arg(args, void*);
    ptrint = (unsigned int)&ptr;
    my_putstr("0x7fff");
    my_putstr(my_itoa_base_uint(ptrint, 16));

    return (1);
}
```

Output:

```
MY_PRINTF:'0x7fff505247b0'
   PRINTF:'0x7fff50524a20'
```

As you can see the last three char are wrong, is there any documentation about that?

Comment: `my_itoa_base_uint` is broken? Or any other `my_*`.

Comment: Where is `my_printf`?

Comment: The standard only allows to cast a pointer to `(u)intptr_t` and back safely. Any other integer type is not guaranteed to store a pointer completely. Briefly: **Don't use any other integer type than `(u)intptr_t`.**

Comment: Thank you for the advice :)

Comment: The fact that your code is adding the `0x7fff` prefix is indicative of problems.  You're expecting to be able to hold 64-bit pointers in 32-bit `unsigned int` — this is not a recipe for happiness, and not all pointers in 64-bit machines (are you on a Mac, perchance?) are prefixed with 0x7fff.  Using `uintptr_t` will get you around the issues.

Comment: Yep, I'm on mac.
Now I'm just printing `0x` (without 7fff) then the address converted in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second case, you're converting the address of the variable `ptr` to an `int`, rather than its value (the pointer you're interested in).

Replacing `(unsigned int)&ptr;` with `(unsigned int)ptr;` will give you consistent values.

And an additional aside: there's no guarantee `unsigned int` is large enough to represent the pointer value: you should use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` from `<stdint.h>`.